# How can I get a data-variable from each element with a class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, each, jquery-data

Given the following markup, how can I return with jQuery all the `data-foo` values with the class `.bar`?

```
<ul id="foobar-list">
    <li data-foo="1">Alpha</li>
    <li data-foo="2" class="bar">Beta</li>
    <li data-foo="3" class="bar">Gamma</li>
    <li data-foo="4">Delta</li>
</ul>
```

Here's my progress so far:

```
var arr = [];
$('#foobar-list .bar').each(function() {
    var arr[] = $(this).data('foo');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using `.map:`

```
var arr = $(".bar[data-foo]").map(function() {
    return $(this).data("foo");
}).get();
```

Comment: Yup i would've used map as well to convert one collection to another..  +1

Comment: Confirmed: http://jsfiddle.net/SGMm7/ Thanks.  Out of curiosity, what is the advantage of using `map` over `arr.push`?

Comment: @Ryan -- Not sure about the actual performance gains (have to setup a jsperf for that), overall, it's more convenient. No worries about declaring an array outside the loop or pushing, simply give a selector and return the criteria!

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
var arr = [];
$('#foobar-list .bar').each(function() {
    arr.push($(this).data('foo'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the var inside the loop - you're redeclaring the variable.

```
var arr = [];
$('#foobar-list .bar').each(function(index) {
    arr[index] = $(this).data('foo');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QfSLE/

Comment: this will overwrite the array each time rather than adding to it